# My scraper takes hours to complete using selenium. Can I make it faster?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this website of specific informations about teams that play in a day
https://www.flashscore.ro/
So my take is I use selenium to load the website and log IN to it and then I use beautifulSoup to get the links to all the matches . A link looks like this https://www.flashscore.ro/meci/Ao6VwJq3/#sumar-meci.
After that I use beautifulSoup again to get the link to every team in every match (for example: https://www.flashscore.ro/echipa/west-brom/CCBWpzjj/). until here its ok . everything works pretty fast .
And from this page I want the half time score from the last team's games
[image]

But here the problem is that I cant get those scores with beautiful soup. and If I use selenium I have to open each link one after another and get the info I want . and with 200 to 700 games on a Sunday .that means 1400 links to open . that takes hours .
this is the code I use to get the name of the team and the score and write them in a file. in selenium

```
for echipa in linkul_echipei:
        try:
            driver.get(echipa)
        except:
            pass
        SCORUL = []
        nume_echipa = driver.find_element_by_class_name('teamHeader__name').text
        scor_prima = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('event__part')
        for scor in scor_prima:
            try:
                SCORUL.append(scor.text.translate({ord(i): None for i in '()-'}))
            except:
                pass
        

    punctaj_scor = []
    for i in SCORUL:
        punctaj_scor.append(int(i[0])+int(i[-1]))
    


    try:
        if punctaj_scor.count(0) >=5:
            sub_1.write(str(punctaj_scor.count(0))+'/'+str(len(punctaj_scor))+ ' | '+nume_echipa+ ' | '+nume_home + nume_away+'\n')
            
    except:
        pass
```

Can I use beautifulsoup here ? I couldn't find that element by class name ('event__part')
Or can I make it faster in some way with selenium ?
thanks !